# WatchOS2 access to heart sensor data

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-2, healthkit

Has apple released any documentation on how to access data from the infrared and photodiodes that make up the heart rate sensor with the new release of watchOS 2.0.1?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The OS gives you access to the HealthKit. Within the HealthKit you have an access to the heart sensor data.

You may find this link useful:

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKWorkout_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014744)

Comment: But there is no way to directly access those sensors correct?

Comment: @GregMiller, no. You cannot hijack the sensors in any way as of today